# Microsoft InkPicture becomes unusable

Tags: delphi, tablet-pc

I have an application, the forms that users see have Microsoft INK fields on them for them to write in.

On the odd occasion, these fields that the users write in become unusable, IE the user cannot enter any data into these ink fields (either using a pen or even mouse).  The behaviour of the ink component is like its being marked as read only and the pen (or mouse).

Its a random occurrence that resolves after re-starting the application.
Does anyone know of or has seen this kind of behaviour using the Microsoft Tablet API or its components??

This issue is happening on Vista and Windows 7.  I thought it might have been the drivers for the Wacom screens but it turns out that it also happens with mouse as well.

Comment: This still has not been resolved.  No response from Microsoft either and stock scripted responses from Wacom (pointless)

Answer (score 0):

If at any point you disable the inkpicture, the inkenable property gets locked to disabled.  It will raise no errors, but the effect the end-user sees will be an unusable inkpicture.  You may consider testing if inkenable is set after you set it you can then create a method to destroy and recreate the inkpicture object or back out of that part of the application.

"When you set the Enabled property of a container control to false, all of its contained controls are disabled as well."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.ink.inkpicture.inkenabled(v=vs.85).aspx